# Can you use the word 'that' after a comma?

Tags: grammar

My friend told me that you can NEVER use a comma before 'that' but I think you can. Can someone clear this up for us?

Comment: Here's a question from [ell.se]: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/9154/use-of-commas-before-that

Comment: If your friend really said such a thing, that was completely wrong of him/her.  :-)

Comment: Generally that is true, at least with relative clauses and content clauses. The main exceptions are supplementary adjuncts with the form of interpolations as in "Connective tissues are avascular, that is they don't have their own blood supply".

Comment: "Before Joyce could look up, that kangaroo passed her."

Comment: I think the OP was talking about the subordinator "that", not the determiner.

Comment: No, that would be silly.

Answer (score 5):

Of course you can use *that* after a comma. Like any rule made up by a well-meaning teacher, understanding why it is sometimes true and what the exceptions are will make you a better writer.

It sounds like your friend's advice is specific to restrictive clauses, which are often headed by **that**. For a relative clause introduced by a relative pronoun (that, who, which, whom, whose), it is called *restrictive* if the information is essential to the sentence, that is, if the clause restricts or defines the meaning of a noun phrase; it is called *nonrestrictive* if the clause provides supplemental or additional information.

For example, the [Walden University Writing Center](https://academicguides.waldenu.edu/writingcenter/grammar/clauses) uses these examples for restrictive and nonrestrictive clauses:

> The book **that she read** was important for her literature review. (restrictive; the clause *that she read* specifies the book that was important for her lit review)
>
> The participants **who were interviewed** volunteered to be part of the study. (restrictive; the clause *who were interviewed* specifies which participants volunteered to be part of the study)
>
> Walden University, **which is entirely online**, has main administrative offices in Baltimore and Minneapolis. (nonrestrictive; *which is entirely online* gives added information about Walden but does not help specify the noun, as Walden University is already specific enough)

No comma is used before a restrictive clause; commas are used before and after a nonrestrictive clause. Because restrictive clauses tend to be headed by *that* and nonrestrictive clauses tend to be headed by *which*, your friend's advice would hold true in many cases - no comma should go before the *that* in a relative clause.

That said, there are other uses for *that* that may accommodate a comma. For example, take this usage of *that is*:

> A relative clause is called *restrictive* if the information is essential to the sentence, **that is**, if the clause restricts or defines the meaning of a noun phrase

"That is" introduces a restatement or further explanation of what was just said. It is customarily preceded by commas. It is also sometimes followed by commas, though this is a source for greater debate [even on StackExchange](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/170672/when-is-a-comma-appropriate-when-using-that-is).

We could imagine other situations. What if a parenthetical statement, one customarily set off by commas, precedes *that*? Would we automatically delete the comma only because *that* appears? No.

> While the majority of commentators believe, **as we do, that** result-based punishment in the criminal law does not advance the goal of deterrence, a minority of scholars contest this issue. (John Boeglin and Zachary Shapiro. "[A Theory of Differential Punishment](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=2910719)," Vanderbilt Law Review 70.5, 2017.)

Comment: Will be comprehensive if the use of 'that' as a determiner after a comma  is explained

Comment: @Arun, there's not really any reason, that I can think of, why one _shouldn't_ put 'that' after a comma.

Comment: @marcellothearcane Absolutely. In fact, OLD has used 'that' after a comma even when used in a relative clause. https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/bassinet?q=bassinet

Comment: @Arun Does the baby look like a basket? ;) In the linked example, the relative clause modifies "a small bed," and the comma separates it from the prepositional phrase to emphasize that the bed is not for **a baby that looks like a basket**. I could probably find other ways commas go before *that*, but my primary purpose was to respond to the rule OP described.